# jQuery UI Dialog - modal window temporarily covers dialog during effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

My modal window covers the dialog for the duration of the effect that brings it in - as if the z-index bringing it to the top only kicks in once the effect has ended.

Anyone any ideas?!

The code is below... Of course if I don't use a show effect then it comes straight to the fore and isn't a problem.

```
$(function(){
        var dialogOpts = {
        autoOpen:       false,
        height:         400,
        width:          800,
        position:       ["center", "center"],
        modal:          true,
        closeOnEscape:  true,
        stack:          false,
        draggable:      false,
        hide:           "clip",
        show:           "clip"
    };

        $("#why").dialog(dialogOpts);
```

Comment: Could you post your code please.

Comment: I also have this problem. Hopefully I will figure it out, or someone will post a solution. =/

Answer (score 0):

I can see this problem also using jsFiddle code.  I believe the problem exists during the `show: "clip"` action, try changing it to "slide" or "fade" or something and see if that gets rid of your problem.

If it works then you know the problem resides with how jQuery handles the "clip" action, I wouldn't know what to do past this point however.

Hope this helps...